# Get attribute from xml file php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, attributes, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <abc-response>
   <error-messages>
    <errors code="302">
         User does not have access to this Product 
    </errors>
  </error-messages>
</abc-response>
```

am using simplexml_load_string and using the attribute function to get the code and I keep getting a null value.

```
 $results = simplexml_load_string($response);

 $errorCode = $results->attributes()->{'errors'};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to navigate to the element with the attribute you want. There are lots of ways.

```
echo $results->{'error-messages'}->errors['code'];//302
```

This works just fine since there's just one `error-messages` and one `errors`. If you had several, you could use array notation to indicate the one you want. So the line below also echoes `302`

```
echo $results->{'error-messages'}[0]->errors[0]['code'];
```

You could even use `xpath`, a query language to traverse xml. The `//` will return all nodes by name:

```
echo $results->xpath('//errors')[0]->attributes()->code; //302
```

`echo` shows a number, but it's still an object. If you'd like to capture just the integer, cast it like this:

```
$errorCode = (int) $results->{'error-messages'}->errors['code'];
```

Check out this [really helpful intro](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).